# Converting latitude and longidue into multipolygon

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I have been trying to convert the latitude and longitude into multipolygon object so that that I can use tmap library to plot it, but I am not able to that. Converting useing st_as_sf is not wroking, can some help me? I am attaching sample data set.

```
coor<-structure(list(Type = c("Registry", "Registry", "Registry", "Registry", "Platform", "Registry"),`Location of coordinating center` = c("USA","USA", "USA", "USA", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"),`3ISO code` = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "GBR", "GBR"), `WHO region code` = c("AMR","AMR", "AMR", "AMR", "EUR", "EUR"), city = c("Philadelphia","Chicago", "Washington", "Alexandria", "London", "Manchester"), lat = c(32.7761, 41.8373, 38.9047, 38.8185, 51.50853, 53.4794), lng = c(-89.1221, -87.6862, -77.0163, -77.0861, -0.12574, -2.2453)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and if possible your expected output, a sketch may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments to this:

- you are unlikely to convert your data to multiopolygon object, since you have only a single coordinate pair for each city / that spells points to me, not polygons
- you were on a right track with `sf::st_as_sf()`

What you need to do in your `st_as_sf` call to make it work properly is

1. specify columns in your data frame that have coordinate information and
2. give a meaning to the figures (are they degrees? meters? or has an American been feeling patriotic and encoded the data in feet?) you use a coordinate reference system (crs) for that.

For long lat data EPSG:4326 is usually a good default.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

sf_coords <- coor %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326)

tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(sf_coords) +
  tm_bubbles(size = 5, col = "red", id = "city") +
  tm_basemap(leaflet::providers$Stamen.Watercolor)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped. But unfortunately I am not an American.